# Laravel File Manager not load file list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem with Laravel File Manager.

I am very beginner in Laravel.

I have this component in my project (Laravel 5.8):

UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

```
<textarea id="qqq1" name="article-ckeditor" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
<textarea id="qqq2" name="article-ckeditor" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
<script src="http://test.test/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(".ckeditor").each(function () {
                CKEDITOR.replace( $(this).attr('id'), {

                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&amp;_token=',
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: 'http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&amp;_token=',
                    height: 800
                });
            });
```

When I open uploader I have path:

```
http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager?type=Images&CKEditor=qqq1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=pl
```

my route file (web.php):

```
Route::get('cms/laravel-filemanager', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\LfmController@show');
    Route::post('cms/laravel-filemanager/upload', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\UploadController@upload');
```

My lfm.php:

```
<?php

/*


return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'use_package_routes'       => true,

    // // Use relative paths (without domain)
    // 'relative_paths'           => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Multi-User Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'allow_multi_user'         => true,

    'allow_share_folder'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Folder Names
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHandler class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHandler::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'user_folder_name'         => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    'shared_folder_name'       => 'shares',

    'thumb_folder_name'        => 'thumbs',

    'folder_categories'        => [
        'file'  => [
            'folder_name'  => 'files',
            'startup_view' => 'grid',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
        ],
        'image' => [
            'folder_name'  => 'photos',
            'startup_view' => 'list',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'application/pdf',
                'text/plain',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'disk'                     => 'public',

    'rename_file'              => false,

    'alphanumeric_filename'    => false,

    'alphanumeric_directory'   => false,

    'should_validate_size'     => false,

    'should_validate_mime'     => false,

    // permissions to be set when create a new folder or when it creates automatically with thumbnails
    'create_folder_mode'       => 0755,

    // permissions to be set on file upload.
    'create_file_mode'         => 0644,

    // If true, it will attempt to chmod the file after upload
    'should_change_file_mode'  => true,

    // behavior on files with identical name
    // setting it to true cause old file replace with new one
    // setting it to false show `error-file-exist` error and stop upload
    'over_write_on_duplicate'  => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes'         => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    'thumb_img_width'          => 200,

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | jQuery UI options
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'resize_aspectRatio'       => false,

    'resize_containment'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'file_type_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    'file_icon_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'fa-file-pdf-o',
        'doc'  => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'docx' => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'xls'  => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'xlsx' => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'zip'  => 'fa-file-archive-o',
        'gif'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpg'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpeg' => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'png'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'ppt'  => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
        'pptx' => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
     */
    'php_ini_overrides'        => [
        'memory_limit' => '256M',
    ],
];
```

When I open Laravel File Manager from CkEditor I have this:

https://ibb.co/4txGhcQ

In console I have error:
1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager/folders?working_dir=&type=Images&_=1558341378662

2. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager/folders?working_dir=&type=Images&_=1558341378662

When I copy to browser: 
http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager- I have this: 
https://ibb.co/nb6GTSj

When I copy to browser: 
http://test.test/cms/laravel-filemanager/folders?working_dir=&type=Images&_=1558341378662

i have 404 not found

How repair this?

Answer (score 0):

Do lfm.php return array? In file "return" is commented.

Also has similar problem. Problem was with URL prefix in /config/lfm.php file.

```
// Middlewares which should be applied to all package routes.
// For laravel 5.1 and before, remove 'web' from the array.
'middlewares' => ['web', 'admin'],

// The url to this package. Change it if necessary.
'url_prefix' => 'cms/laravel-filemanager',
```